# How to change GridView row background based on if the rows object is part of an another collection available on viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm

I have basic `gridView` filled with columns. However, I would like to change the **background** of a row based on the fact that if the object is found on another collection declared on the `viewModel`, other than the `itemsSource` of `gridView`.

Any suggestion how I could achieve this?

I have looked into **IValueConverter** but in that case I need to access the `viewModel` collection OR database from the converter, and I assume this is not a good thing?

> I am using .NET 4.5, WPF

Comment: Why you are not creating a property which tell that current records exist in another collection and then you can use IValueConverter OR use data trigger to change the background color.

Comment: It would be the easiest way, however I was looking for some alternative approaches in this particular case.

Comment: Ok, Then you use Multi value converter and pass the collection and value to be compare. Check for the existence in collection and then based on that you can change the color. When using Multi value converter and passing the collection you need to use the relative source to find the parent element whose data context  is set to you view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an IMultiValueConverter and bind to both the object itself and the other collection, e.g.:

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:TheConverter x:Key="TheConverter" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TheConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="." />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.TheOtherCollectionProperty" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

---

```
public class TheConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length < 2)
            return false;

        YourDataObject obj = values[0] as YourDataObject;
        System.Collections.IList collection = values[1] as System.Collections.IList;

        return collection != null && collection.Contains(obj);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```